# How to enable Chinese language on keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language, chinese

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 English version. I can view Chinese characters on the system, but I would like to key Chinese characters as well. I would like to know any language package to actually to key Chinese in the system?

Your information and help is great appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to "system settings" -> "Text Entry" (under Personal), and add "Chinese (Bopomofo)" or "Chinese (Pinyin)". It might be a good idea to press the "Show current input source in the menu bar" too.

Comment: @user3528144: Let me add that https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html, which is for 14.04 but applies mostly to 13.10 as well, is probably useful to study.